# How to calculate ordinal number on columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have dataset with columns user_id and type:

| user_id | type | ordinal_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | request | 1 |
| 1 | request | 1 |
| 1 | request | 1 |
| 1 | request | 1 |
| 1 | payment | 1 |
| 2 | request | 1 |
| 2 | request | 1 |
| 2 | payment | 1 |
| 2 | request | 2 |
| 2 | payment | 2 |

I want to fill column ordinal_number values likes in tables.
If type == payment then assign a ordinal number and fill all previous row (type==request) on user_id values ordinal number.

for some users it may only be request and may be several payments in a row.

Comment: You should clarify what should happen in case of multiple "payment" or "request" after a payment

Comment: payment always have request in previous

Comment: And are multiple request/payment possible? or something like R-R-P-R-P-R"?

Comment: and what should be the output then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can identify "payments"; `groupby` "user_id" and in each group, reverse the Series, find `cumsum`, then reverse it back.

```
def assign_num(x):
    s = x[::-1].cumsum()
    # must subtract from max value to get an ascending Series
    return s.iat[-1] + 1 - s[::-1]

df['ordinal_number'] = df['type'].eq('payment').groupby(df['user_id']).apply(assign_num)
```

Output:

```
   user_id     type  ordinal_number
0        1  request               1
1        1  request               1
2        1  request               1
3        1  request               1
4        1  payment               1
5        2  request               1
6        2  request               1
7        2  payment               1
8        2  request               2
9        2  payment               2
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to set a counter on "payment" and backfill it per group:

```
m = df['type'].eq('payment')

df['ordinal_number'] = (m.cumsum().where(m)
                         .groupby(df['user_id'])
                         .bfill().astype(int)
                       )
```

Or to use the value or "user_id" as start value:

```
df['ordinal_number'] = (df['user_id'].where(df['type'].eq('payment'))
                         .groupby(df['user_id'])
                         .bfill().astype(int)
                       )
```

output:

```
   user_id     type  ordinal_number
0        1  request               1
1        1  request               1
2        1  request               1
3        1  request               1
4        1  payment               1
5        2  request               2
6        2  request               2
7        2  payment               2
```

Comment: I've the error: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Comment: @spacenew can you provide in your question an example where this error happens

Comment: for some users it may only be request and may be several payments in a row.